# Why am I encountering method errors when the values clearly match up?

Tags: arrays, methods, double, java.util.scanner

```
            for (int i=0; i<n.length; i++)
        {
            double a=avg(double[] n);
            System.out.println("Over the five entered tests/assignments,");
            System.out.println("this student achieved an average of "+a+".");
        }
}
public static double avg(double[] n)
{
    double sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n.length; i++)
    {
        sum=sum+n[i];
    }
    return sum/n.length;
}
```

}
The code above the double avg classification is part of void main. I'm not sure what's causing it, but on line 20 (double a=avg(double[] n);), I get two errors: one on 'avg' (method not applicable for the arguments) and another on ']' (Syntax error, should be followed by '::' but that just bricks it further).

This is making me worry to hell and back. I am new to coding, and this is part of a basic assignment involving user-based array input in my Java-based Programming course.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your code snippet, an array of `double`s is declared above the code snippet you shared.
In the method call `double a=avg(double[] n);`, you're declaring a new `double[]` with the name variable name `n` as you defined above.
You don't need to pass the `double[]` type to the method call. If you change this call to `double a=avg(n);`, the code snippet should compile & run (given that you've initialized the `double[]` with a couple of values in the lines above the snippet). Hope this helps!